# Leaflet : display problems during deployment

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, deployment, leaflet

I deployed my blog via SSH on Infomaniak, work with Symfony and I recently added a Leaflet map on it. In a development environment, no problem, the markers appear and the filters used work well.

Once deployed, the map is displayed, no markers appear and the filters do not display anything.

The console displays these errors:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ().
By clicking on the filter checkboxes: the error comes from the fetch.

Do you have an idea ?

Dev environment:

[image: dev]

Deployed

[image: deployed]

map.js :

```
//Icon of the jerseys on the map
let iconPicture = L.icon ({
    iconUrl: '/assets/images/cycling.png',
    iconSize: [25, 25],
    popupAnchor:  [0, -10]
});

 //Card initialization function
 function initMap() {
    var map = L.map('mapId').setView([48.833, 2.333], 10); 

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 13,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoieWFubnJhdWxldCIsImEiOiJja3BjYzV0bTQwMTBqMzBvOGR1ZTBweDcxIn0.5jvTEj-WaEiKxIpSFpEu1Q'
    }).addTo(map);

    //Checkbox for filters by years
    var command = L.control();
    command.onAdd = function (map) {
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'command');
        div.innerHTML += '<h5>Filtres <br> par collection</h5>';
        div.innerHTML += '<form><input id="checkboxAll" + type="checkbox"/> Tous les maillots</form>';
        div.innerHTML += '<form><input id="checkbox50_60" + type="checkbox"/> Années 50 - 60</form>';
        div.innerHTML += '<form><input id="checkbox70" + type="checkbox"/> Années 70</form>';
        div.innerHTML += '<form><input id="checkbox80" +  type="checkbox"/> Années 80</form>';
        div.innerHTML += '<form><input id="checkbox90" + type="checkbox"/> Années 90</form>';
        return div;
    };
    //Add leaflet legend control
    command.addTo(map);

    //Constant for checkbox filters
    const cyclingShirts = document.getElementById('checkboxAll');
    const cyclingShirts50_60 = document.getElementById('checkbox50_60');
    const cyclingShirts70 = document.getElementById('checkbox70');
    const cyclingShirts80 = document.getElementById('checkbox80');
    const cyclingShirts90 = document.getElementById('checkbox90');

    //Creating layers and clusters with leaflet class
    var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

    var markersGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
        //Added options from the github documentation
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 13,
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
        removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true,
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            var count = cluster.getChildCount();
            return L.divIcon({
                html: count,
                className: 'cluster',
                iconSize: null
            })
        }
    });

    var markersGroup50_60 = L.markerClusterGroup({
        //Added options from the github documentation
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 13,
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
        removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true,
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            var count = cluster.getChildCount();
            return L.divIcon({
                html: count,
                className: 'cluster',
                iconSize: null
            })
        }
    });

    var markersGroup70 = L.markerClusterGroup({
        //Added options from the github documentation
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 13,
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
        removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true,
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            var count = cluster.getChildCount();
            return L.divIcon({
                html: count,
                className: 'cluster',
                iconSize: null
            })
        }
    });

    var markersGroup80 = L.markerClusterGroup({
        //Added options from the github documentation
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 13,
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
        removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true,
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            var count = cluster.getChildCount();
            return L.divIcon({
                html: count,
                className: 'cluster',
                iconSize: null
            })
        }
    });

    var markersGroup90 = L.markerClusterGroup({
        //Added options from the github documentation
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 13,
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
        removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true,
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
            var count = cluster.getChildCount();
            return L.divIcon({
                html: count,
                className: 'cluster',
                iconSize: null
            })
        }
    });

    // 'checkboxAll' checked at the begining
    document.getElementById('checkboxAll').checked = true;
    if (cyclingShirts.checked === true) {
        // get the method map form the apiController
        fetch("/api/map")
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(result => {
            result.forEach( element => {
                //Get the coordinates from the Promise to add them to the LayerGroup
                layerGroup = new L.marker([element.latitude, element.longitude], {icon: iconPicture})
                    .bindPopup(function (layer) {
                        if (element.years == 'Années 50-60') {
                            return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection50_60/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                            "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection50_60" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                        }
                        else if (element.years == 'Années 70') {
                            return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection70/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                            "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection70" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                        }
                        else if (element.years == 'Années 80') {
                            return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection80/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                            "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection80" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                        }
                        else if (element.years == 'Années 90') {
                            return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection90/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                            "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection90" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                        }
                }, {className: 'pop-up-leaflet', direction: 'top'},
                )
                markersGroup.addLayer(layerGroup);
            });
            //Adds all markers to the clusterGroup
            map.addLayer(markersGroup);
        })
        .catch(() => console.error('error'));
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Function for add or remove the markers on the map
    function filterAll() {
        //If the checkbox is checked then we add the markers on the map
        if (cyclingShirts.checked === true) {
            document.getElementById('checkbox50_60').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('checkbox70').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('checkbox80').checked = false;
            document.getElementById('checkbox90').checked = false;
            //Asynchronously retrieves data with the server and returns an object of type Promise
            fetch("/api/map")
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(result => {
                result.forEach( element => {
                    //Get the coordinates from the Promise to add them to the LayerGroup
                    layerGroup = new L.marker([element.latitude, element.longitude], {icon: iconPicture})
                        .bindPopup(function (layer) {
                            if (element.years == 'Années 50-60') {
                                return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection50_60/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                                "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection50_60" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                            }
                            else if (element.years == 'Années 70') {
                                return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection70/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                                "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection70" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                            }
                            else if (element.years == 'Années 80') {
                                return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection80/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                                "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection80" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                            }
                            else if (element.years == 'Années 90') {
                                return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection90/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                                "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection90" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                            }
                    }, {className: 'pop-up-leaflet', direction: 'top'},
                    )
                    markersGroup.addLayer(layerGroup);
                });
                //Adds all markers to the clusterGroup
                map.addLayer(markersGroup);
                //Delete the others clusterGroup
                markersGroup50_60.clearLayers();
                markersGroup70.clearLayers();
                markersGroup80.clearLayers();
                markersGroup90.clearLayers();
            })
            .catch(() => console.error('error'));
        //If the box is not checked, we delete the markers on the map
        } else if (cyclingShirts.checked === false) {
            fetch("/api/map")
            .then(response => { 
                return response.json()
            })
                .then(result => {
                    markersGroup.clearLayers();
                })
                .catch(() => console.error('error'));
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('checkboxAll').addEventListener('click', filterAll, false);

    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    function filter50_60() {
        if (cyclingShirts50_60.checked === true) {
            document.getElementById('checkboxAll').checked = false;
            fetch("/api/map")
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(result => {
                markersGroup.clearLayers();
            })
            .catch(() => console.error('error'));

            fetch("/api/filter50_60")
            .then(response => { 
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(result => {
                result.forEach( element => {
                    layerGroup = new L.marker([element.latitude, element.longitude], {icon: iconPicture})
                        .bindPopup(function (layer) {
                            return "<span>" + element.name + "</span>" + "<br>" +  "<div class='img-hover-zoom'>" + "<a href=" + "/collection50_60/" + element.id + ">" + "<img class='picturePopup' src=/assets/images/uploads/" + element.pictureFront + ">" + "</a>" + "</div>" +
                            "<br>" + element.city +"<br>" + "<a href=" + "/collection50_60" + ">" + element.years + "</a>"
                    }, {className: 'pop-up-leaflet', direction: 'top'},
                    )
                    markersGroup50_60.addLayer(layerGroup);
                });
                map.addLayer(markersGroup50_60);
            })
            .catch(() => console.error('error'));
        }  else if (cyclingShirts.checked === false) {
            fetch("/api/filter50_60")
            .then(response => { 
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(result => {
                markersGroup50_60.clearLayers();
            })
            .catch(() => console.error('error'));
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('checkbox50_60').addEventListener('click', filter50_60, false);

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
(and three others filters (70,80,90)

}

window.onload = function(){
    // Initialization function that runs when the DOM is loaded
    initMap();
};
```

ApiController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\CyclingShirtRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * This controller will return Json responses for the Leaflet map ajax requests
 * @Route( "/api", name="api_")
 */
class ApiController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/map", name="map")
     * Collect all years cycling shirts
     * @return Response
     */
    public function map(CyclingShirtRepository $shirtsRepository): Response
    {
        $cyclingShirt = $shirtsRepository->findAll();
        return $this->json($cyclingShirt, 200);
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/filter50_60", name="filter50_60")
    * Collect cycling shirts 50s and 60s
    * @return Response
    */
    public function filter5060(CyclingShirtRepository $shirtsRepository): Response
    {
        $filter5060 = $shirtsRepository->findByYears('Années 50-60');
        return $this->json($filter5060, 200);
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/filter70", name="filter70")
    * Collect cycling shirts 70s
    * @return Response
    */
    public function filter70(CyclingShirtRepository $shirtsRepository): Response
    {
        $filter70 = $shirtsRepository->findByYears('Années 70');
        return $this->json($filter70, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly the api your are requesting data has a request limit. Have you checked that? Moreover in your code it seems you are requesting data  7 different times

Comment: Good question, I looked at the documentation but I can't find this kind of information, do you know where I can find it ?

Comment: I don't know which API you are using. I can see the url but googling it does not give any result. Could you provide the API url docs?

Comment: Leaflet : https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html, but i don't see where to look for the url information

Comment: I mean the API to load cycling data e.g `cycling/api/....` not the map rendering library

Comment: I don't use an API for this. Just an entity, the repository and the ApiController (I added 3/4 of the Controller to the post, the 2 lasts methods 80 and 90 are the same as the filter70)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.` in front of you url path. `/api/map/` should be `./api/map/`

With a starting `/` your path not starting from the current folder, it starts from the main-domain url. For example: `www.domain.com/api/map/` instead of `www.domain.com/infomaniak/myproject/api/map/`

Comment: I changed my url paths, but unfortunately that didn't change anything. On the other hand, the card is still long to load the first time.